# Processing a failed payment in square (should I use a new Idempotency key if the error is related to the customers bank)

Tags: square

I am using square to take payments from customers.
When a payment request fails for a reason like insufficient funds etc I want to retry it a few hours later. We are using Card On File so we have the ability to do this.
Should I use the same idempotency key or a new one?

https://developer.squareup.com/docs/build-basics/common-api-patterns/idempotency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to generate a new `idempotency_key` for each new CreatePayment request with the card on file.